# Unusual pattern of data corruption over serial port

Tags: windows, serial-port, ascii, serial-communication, hyperterminal

I'm testing my application's receipt of data over a serial port by sending data from Windows HyperTerminal and this mostly works. For example if I send :

**The Quick Brown Fox**

I receive :

**The Quick Brown Fox**

However, if I send :

**UUUUUUUUUUU**

I receive

**UUÕUÕUÕUÕUÕ**

or if I send :

**aaaaaaaaaaa**

I receive :

**aaáaáaáaáaá**

so for any repeated character string longer than 2, then the 3rd, 5th, 7th etc. characters are corrupted by having their high bit set.

The serial port settings on both machines are identical.

Comment: When you say, serial port settings are the same, does this include the data bits, stop bit, and parity bit (ie, 8N1, or 7E1)?

Also, if you are using two computers, are they connected by a null modem cable?

Comment: Could be caused by a baudrate clock mismatch between the transmitter and receiver but that's pretty unusual these days and doesn't repeat like that.  Try lowering the baudrate.  Somewhat more likely is a bad electrical connection, a floating ground problem.  Check if the GND pins are properly connected, pin 5 on the DB9 connector.

Comment: Using 9600 baud, 8 bits, 1 stop bit, no parity on both computers

Comment: Continuity check looks okay

Comment: are you using the same cabling (physically) for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found this: http://seetron.com/archive/html/ht_tip1.htm

The last paragraph says:

> Saved configurations can be corrupted in odd ways. The most obvious
>   symptom is that typing the same character three times in a row causes
>   the third instance of the character to be sent incorrectly. In other
>   cases, the terminal program fails to work altogether. The only fix we
>   know of is to create a new configuration from scratch, as described
>   above.

Sound familiar?